# Comparator in Java, using it with different fields

Tags: java, collections, comparator

Is it possible to call a comparator from a method in Java? I have the following piece of code and I am supposed to write a class which has a method addComparator which I assume has to add Comparator somehow. The code is (it is not a full version, I am just trying to understand what I am supposed to do and how to implement this):

```
 ComparatorChain chain = new ComparatorChain();
 chain.addComparator(new sortByTitle());
 chain.addComparator(new sortByDirector());
 Collections.sort(library.getItem(),chain);
```

Can someone give me a hint on how I could implement this. 
Thanks.

Comment: comparators can be chained using the thenComparing method which just takes another comparator, the final result will be a comparator that simply runs all comparators you passed in the order you defined them

Comment: Do you just want to sort by multiple parameters (Title, Director) or need the option to chain ?

Comment: I believe, I need to chain but I am not sure. But I have to use the above code as a Driver. So, I guess I have to create a class ComparatorChain with a method addComparator and somehow put Comparator (class(sortByTitle) (sortByDirector) in this method. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: There's nothing special about a comparator: it's just some class that implements the `Comparator<T>` interface, which means it has a method `compare` that you call to compare two items. So if you have `Comparator<Type> comp` and two `Type` instances `t1` and `t2`, use `comp.compare(t1, t2)` to compare them.

Comment: By the way, this functionality is now built into the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface as of Java 8 and later. See the [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) method for chaining together comparators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have :

```
class ComparatorChain implements Comparator<TypeToBeSorted> {....};
class SortByTitle     implements Comparator<TypeToBeSorted> {....};
class SortByDirector  implements Comparator<TypeToBeSorted> {....};
```

And class `ComparatorChain` has 2 objects like :

```
private SortByTitle sortByTitle;
private SortByDirector sortByDirector;
```

class `ComparatorChain` could implement:

```
public int compare(TypeToBeSorted o1, TypeToBeSorted o2) {
    int comByTitle = (sortByTitle == null ) ? 0 : sortByTitle.compare(o1, o2);
    int comByDirector = (sortByDirector == null ) ? 0 : sortByDirector.compare(o1, o2);
    //add logic 
    return ......;
}
```

`chain.addComparator(new sortByTitle());`    should initialize sortByTitle

```
void addComparator(SortByTitle sortByTitle) { this.sortByTitle = sortByTitle; }
```

`chain.addComparator(new sortByDirector());` should initialize sortByDirector.
 You can have one method to do both by using `instanceof`

**Edit** following @LeonardBrünings comment: The answer above should not be regarded as a proper implementation, but more as an attempt to answer

> Can someone give me a hint

with something simple enough to start with. 
For a more dynamic generic and flexible implementation you could have in `ComparatorChain`:

```
List<Comparator<TypeToBeSorted>> comperatorList  = new ArrayList<>(); //or better use generics
```

Add Comparators at the desired order by

```
void addComparator(Comparator<TypeToBeSorted> comperator) { comperatorList.add(comperator); }
```

And implement implement `compare` using comperatorList elements.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean. Could you provide any insights on what this means:   chain.addComparator(new sortByDirector());                                   
   I am not sure how to implement a method addComparator in class ComparatorChain.

Comment: chain.addComparator(new sortByTitle()); should initialize sortByTitle .               Could you give an example how it should be initialized.

Comment: @c0der your chain is not really chaining, since you hardcoded the fields, you need to use a list and call the comparators in the order they were added. Exit as soon as you have a non-`0` result or return `0` if there are no comparators left.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings you are absolutely right. My answer should not be regarded as a proper implementation, but more as an attempt to answer "Can someone give me a hint" with something simple enough to start with. For a more dynamic and flexible implementation I would use a Builder Pattern and generics. I added this clarification to the answer